# Select data from the same column

Tags: mysql

I need to select data from the same column with different values?
How do I

```
select * FROM billingorganization WHERE user_id = $user_id && user_id = 0?

<select name="billing_name">

<?php
    $query2 = "SELECT * from billingorganization WHERE user_id = $user_id";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $billing_name = $row3['billing_name'];
        $billing_name_id = $row3['billing_name_id'];

?>

     <option value="<?php echo $billing_name; ?>" ><?php echo $billing_name ;?></option>

<?php
     }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Whats the issue in query ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use OR in your WHERE: user_id = $user_id OR user_id = 0?

Comment: how can a single field user_id can contain two values?

Comment: yes instead of AND you need to use OR in your query

Answer (score 2):

```
select * FROM billingorganization WHERE user_id = $user_id OR user_id = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE user_id IN ($userid,0)
```

It's clear, simple and elegant.